# VBA Code Works in Excel 2010 But Not Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have code in VBA that copies worksheets with the same tab name from different workbooks into one workbook. The workbooks that the code pulls from is in one folder. The code is working fine in Excel 2010 however when I run it in Excel 2013, I get the following 1004 error message: "Sorry, we couldn't find ....xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted." I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting. Has anyone run into this problem or have any ideas why it would be working fine in Excel 2010 and not Excel 2013? Thank you.

```
Sub CombineSheets()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim sPath As String
Dim sFname As String
Dim wBk As Workbook
Dim wSht As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sPath = "PathName\Inputs"
ChDir sPath
sFname = "*"
sFname = Dir(sPath & "\" & sFname & ".xlsx*", vbNormal) <Code bombs here>
wSht = ("Risks")
Do Until sFname = ""
    Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sFname)
    Windows(sFname).Activate
    Sheets(wSht).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    wBk.Close False
    sFname = Dir()
Loop
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Are you sure that file it is trying to reference still exists, in the same location?

Comment: If it bombs on the line you've indicated, it's likely that either you don't have a folder named `Pathname` as a subdirectory of the current directory, or that `PathName` doesn't have a subdirectory named `Inputs`. Have you confirmed that both actually exist? Note that you've made `PathName` a relative directory (meaning it has to exist in the same folder your code is executing in).

Comment: I am sure that the reference still exists and nothing has changed since I last ran it in Excel 2010. The code will be used in 2013 so I'm trying to figure out what the difference could be. Is there a different setting I need to change?

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but you have an "*" on the  wrong side of the ".xlsx" So when you step through the code or when it errors, hover over `sFname` and see what it is showing

Comment: Ken, the Inputs folder is where all the files are. I have an Inputs folder and another folder where the code is being executed. I'm very new with VBA, so would this be causing this issue and is there a way to fix it without moving my Inputs folder?

Comment: Now my code is bombing at Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(sFname). SFname is the name of one of the workbooks I want to copy a tab from.

Comment: And if you `Debug.Print sFname` and then paste that into File Explorer, does Excel open? I typically use a `FileSystemObject` when dealing with files, so I'm not real familiar with the expected behavior of `Dir` and `ChDir`. Can you try a complete path for `sFname` like `c:\users\me\desktop\somefile.xlsx`? Plus, I'm pretty sure you don't need to use `ChDir`

Comment: `sPath`must be a full path name (exemple "c:\MyDirectory"). using `chdir` can be tricky if `curDir` is not where you think ! Try `debug.pring curdir` in immediate window. Also `".xlsx*"` might be `".xls*"`. Also `Workbooks.Open(spath & "\" & sFname)` because `dir` replies with file names without path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this code has previously worked?

If it did, then your application's default file path has probably changed. You can check this with `Debug.Print Application.DefaultFilePath` In any event, you'd be better off defining your full path name explicitly in your `sPath` variable.

If you want to pick up legacy Excel documents then the string in your `Dir` function could just be "*.xls*" (but that would also collect macro-enabled workbooks). I wonder if that was originally intended with the asterix in your code.

There's no need to activate the window, but you might want an error handling line to check whether the "Risks" sheet does exist in the workbook.

There's also some redundancy in your code, so the whole thing ought to work okay as given below:

```
Sub CombineSheets()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFname As String
    Dim wBk As Workbook
    Dim wSht As Worksheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sPath = "PathName\Inputs" 'make this a full path eg "C:\..."
    sFname = Dir(sPath & "\" & "*.xls*", vbNormal)
    Do Until sFname = ""

        'skip if it's this workbook
        If sFname <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFname)

            'check a "Risks" sheet exists
            Set wSht = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wSht = wBk.Sheets("Risks")
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not wSht Is Nothing Then
                wSht.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            End If

            wBk.Close False

        End If

        sFname = Dir()
    Loop
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```